# Cant upload arduino code when ESP8266-01 module is connected

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.teomaragakis.com/hardware/electronics/how-to-connect-an-esp8266-to-an-arduino-uno/) to connect my ESP8266-01 WiFi Module to Arduino UNO with Arduino IDE v. 1.8.13.

[image: Tutorial snippet]

It works and the module can connect to my WiFi.
However, when I try to upload my code, it says:

`avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x30`

What could be the problem, since when I remove the reset pin it uploads the code, but now the WiFi goes down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that there are two ways of wiring your ESP-01 module to the Arduino:

1. Wired so the PC has access to it and the Arduino is effectively disabled, and
2. Wired so the Arduino has access to it

You are wired in configuration 1 at the moment whereby the Arduino is effectively turned off and the USB connection goes direct to the ESP-01. When you try and upload code to the Arduino it's the ESP-01 that the computer is talking to, not the Arduino.

You need to wire it in configuration 2. In this configuration the TX/RX pins of the ESP-01 connect to any two pins of the Arduino except pins 0 and 1, and the RESET pin is not connected to anything. Then you can't talk to the ESP-01 through the serial monitor - instead you have to write code for the Arduino that uses SoftwareSerial to communicate for you.

There are many many tutorials online about communicating between the Arduino and the ESP-01.

Comment: This answers so many questions that I have had. Thanks for explaining in such a clear way. Appreciate it